# El proyecto no sabe cómo ejecutar el perfil con el nombre "ConsoleApp1" y el comando "Project"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

Tengo un programa muy simple en Visual Studio con C# y el framework .NET 6.0. Cuando intento iniciar este programa, tengo esta alerta:

> El proyecto no sabe cómo ejecutar el perfil con el nombre "ConsoleApp1" y el comando "Project".

"ConsoleApp1" es simplemente el nombre del proyecto. Llevo un rato buscando y no encuentro una solución a esto. Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Agregaste los plugin necesarios? seguiste los pasos que se describen luego del error? todo esto esta explicado en la documentacion de como correr un programa c# en las paginas de microsfot...

Answer (score 0):

La solución para tu problema sería:

1. Abrir el Visual Studio Installer.
2. Hacer clic en la opción de modificar la versión de Visual Studio que tengas instalada.
3. Ir a la pestaña de *Cargas de trabajo* y seleccionar la opción de *Desarrollo de escritorio con .NET* y descargarla.

Esto te permite poder trabajar con C#.